# How to forward devices without subnet routing or full Ethernet bridge

Tags: networking

I'm looking for an inventive solution on how to use a small Linux box (R-pi) to put a network printer with no WiFi of its own on a WiFi network.  IE use the r-pi as some form of network bridge.

The two limitations that are making this tricky are:

- the home router does not support setting static routes. So a simple subnet and ipforward solution doesn't work.
- Linux network bridge does not work because WiFi authentication only authorises a single MAC address. So forwarding another devices packet without changing the MAC address will fail.

I would like the solution to be self configuring (I don't want to hard code IP in the printer and forwarding rule for that ip on the R-Pi because I'd like to make it easy to attach extra devices through the Rpi.

I'm wondering if Linux supports any tricks like ARP forwarding or ND forwarding.

Comment: Except the "self configuring" part you could accomplish this with a simple TCP proxy (like "balance" or "haproxy"). There is support for NAT at the link layer via `ebtables`, but I don't know if that would be appropriate for this or not.

Comment: Have a look at [`parprouted`](https://manpages.debian.org/parprouted/parprouted.8). It should do most of what you want. You have to configure your printer with a static IP address because DHCP won't work.

Comment: Even did some tests about this with parprouted + isc-dhcp-relay to get DHCP working. Works, but that's something that can't be given as an answer. It would require a very detailed description of the environment.